# Invalid SSL certificate in Apache

Tags: apache, ssl

I have installed an SSL certificate on my Apache server, but when I access the site via URL from a different machine, an HTTPS error is shown and viewing the certificate details says "this certificate has an invalid digital signature"

If I view the same URL from within the server itself, the certificate is fine and there is no HTTPS error.

I'm not sure what to look for in httpd.conf. Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: Show us the ```ssl.config```. What is your ServerName, which domain is the certificate for? What does ```error_log``` on ```LogLevel Debug``` say?

Answer (score 1):

You could use SSL Labs to find any SSL misconfigurations: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

There you can also see if your certificate is correct and trusted.